# Missing js-translation.json 404

Tags: magento2.4.3

Let me start off with I have tried the most common solutions:

- Refreshing cache
- Building static content etc.

I am unable to enter the admin panel due to this issue as it's stuck in an everlasting load screen.

It appears that on the user side everything is working fine.

```
[2021-12-04 03:41:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2021-12-04 03:41:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2021-12-04 03:41:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2021-12-04 03:41:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' element cannot be added as child to 'product.info.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2021-12-04 03:41:51] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2021-12-04 03:41:51] main.ERROR: Error while translating phrase "%s" in file %s. [] []
[2021-12-04 03:41:51] main.CRITICAL: Error while translating phrase "%s" in file %s. [] []
```

The problem also persists in developer mode while trying to access the admin, there is just simply no way this file gets generated on the admin side.
In the debug logs it shows me the following:

```
[2021-12-04 03:32:03] main.ERROR: Error while translating phrase "%s" in file %s. [] []
[2021-12-04 03:32:03] main.CRITICAL: Error while translating phrase "%s" in file %s. [] []
```

Been looking around for a particular answer or on more information on how the translation works exactly so I could either disable it or fix it.

To clarify the issue:

- Installed Magento 2.4.3 through composer
- Installed it in developer mode.
- Unable to access the admin due to missing js-translate.json file which triggers an eternal loading screen.
- Only traceable error in the debug and exception log is as follows:

```
[2021-12-04 13:18:51] main.CRITICAL: Error while translating phrase "%s" in file %s. [] []
```

- tried to run in production mode with static content, js-translation.json is still not being created (not just populated, it's not created in general)
- reinstalled complete server (CentOS 7, PHP 7.4 + all extensions)
- reinstalled magento through composer
- Same issue is still persists.
- To test for file permission issues i've done the following: Disable SElinux, set 777 for all files with nginx:nginx within the /var/www
- cleared cache and rebuild modules multiple times.

So the question is:
Has anyone have any experience with the js-translation.json not being created and how did you resolve this?
In case this particular case is unknown, has anyone have any knowledge what the dependencies of the translation function are, so i can debug this on a lower level to see if there are issues in either PHP / PHP-FPM and/or extensions.
Has anyone any other insides they can share with me or point me in the direction where should be looking for a solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging the following error was displayed:

`Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Magento\Framework\Locale\TranslatedLists::getCountryTranslation(): Cannot load resource element 'AN' in`

Removing the row AN (Dutch Antilles) from the DB resolves the issue.

`DELETE FROM directory_country WHERE country_id LIKE ’AN’;`

It's not very graceful but it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from - https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Translation/i18n/en_US.csv#L3

you may want to debug this https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/42fe2238acccfd90312c67f2c9ad2702b4a4e6f2/app/code/Magento/Translation/Model/Js/DataProvider.php#L105

and see which file is not correct and failing.

Usually translation work like this - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html#translate_terms

Comment: I will look into this, thank you.